# Application upgrade throws NPE

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I am using JarDiff+Pack200+Signed app/jars

I have application v1.0 that requires j2se version=1.6.0_16
After the 1st installation/download I deploy v2.0 that requires j2se version=1.7+

The upgrade fails on random jars with the Null Pointer Exception
The second attempt to start v2 is always successful.

I have tested it from command line with java 1.6.0_16 and 7u7.
Any ideas what it means?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.applyPatch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.processTempDataFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToTempFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToCache(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine._downloadCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Check the [bug database](http://bugs.sun.com/).

Comment: I did and working with Oracle support on the issue.

Comment: Good work. :)  Please keep us informed of updates.

Comment: Quick update.The issue occurs if you upgrade you app from v1 to v2 as well as java 1.6 to java 7. I tested with Java 7u10 and it fails as well. The issue was escalated, so still waiting for Oracle. will let you know on the solution.

Comment: All issues were resolved in 1.7.0_17